# JQuery rebinding on vs bind after AJAX query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to know why Jquery's `.on` was never called to rebind my submit button after a AJAX call, Since `on` is suppose to replace `.bind` I could not fathom that it was the problem. but i tried various things and the only thing to have worked was to use `.bind` instead of `.on`.

My form is attached to a dropdown list that will generate new data into the form on click. This was done on a AJAX Get call and on success i was selecting the form and using:

`$('#formname').on('submit',function(){})`

And i then tried

`$('#formname').on('submit','form', function(){})`

admittedly i got the above from a question that was never answered.
[jquery-ajax-form-using-onsubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620423/jquery-ajax-form-using-onsubmit)

I also tried attaching the on submit to the body element as it doesn't change with the AJAX function `$('.container').on('submit','#formname', function(){})` suggested here:
[jquery bind functions and triggers after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767919/jquery-event-wont-fire-after-ajax-call)

but that was also ignored. I then tried replacing the type of 'submit' to 'button' then assign `.on('click', etc...` in case you could not rebind a submit button after the form had reached the DOM.

but the only thing that worked was calling `.bind`, i am lost as i am wanting to use the correct standards. my completed code looks like so, note wherever there is a `.bind` it was previously an `.on` which was not invoked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($){
    $('select#<?php echo $dropdown; ?>').on('click', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var form = 'form#<?php echo $gridName; ?>' 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(form).prop('action') ,
            data: { gg:value },
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(htmlResponse){
                var src = $(form , htmlResponse);
                $('.page_1col_col1').html( src );
                //replace the submit with a input buton to tesk on click
                //$('#<?php echo $gridName; ?> input[type="submit"]').prop('type','button');
                $('#<?php echo $gridName; ?>').bind('submit',function (){
                    rowBinding();
                    //replace the submit with a input btn
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: $(form).prop('action'),
                        dataType: "html",
                        cache: false
                    });

                });
            }

        });
    });
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#<?php echo $gridName; ?>').bind('submit',rowBinding);
});


function rowBinding(){ //stuff}</script>
```

Comment: Note, you can replace .bind with .on directly, as the syntax used by .bind completely works with .on. `$('#<?php echo $gridName; ?>').on('submit',function (){` there's nothing wrong with using direct binding on dynamic elements, especially when there is only one of them.

Comment: In my case it didn't, I replaced on with bind and beloved it should have worked hence I am querying why it hasn't . When I submitted the form after a Ajax call nothing generated on the client side was coming back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you got very close to the correct solution, but got tripped up by a minor detail.

Your third example should have worked,

```
$('container').on('submit','#formname', function(){})
```

but `container` probably should have been `'.container'` or
`'#container'`, or even just `document` as `'container'` would select a HTML element of type container.

Try this for a class named container:

```
$('.container').on('submit','#formname', function(){})
```

or this for an id of container:

```
$('#container').on('submit','#formname', function(){})
```

Or just use the document object (not a selector, hence no quotes)

```
$(document).on('submit','#formname', function(){})
```

Or use the body element:

```
$('body').on('submit','#formname', function(){})
```

Basically the deferred syntax of `on` binds to an element that will stick around for the life of the page, listening for the chosen event, and *then* selecting the target element via the selector supplied in the second parameter.

**Update:** Due to a bug related to styling using `'body'` in delegated events is a bad idea. Your default should be `document` if nothing else is closer/convenient. The problem stems from a possible styling issue, where the `body` element gets a computed height of `0` and does not receive any mouse events. `'body'` will likely work with `submit` events in that instance, but `document` is a safer "default" for *all* cases :)

Comment: My 'container' is just generic for the question I was using the $('.page_1col_col1') as that never changed but didn't try just on document I will give that a go. It did work when it was called on doc.ready but it was always after the Ajax when I was trying to rebind my submit I was getting no where.

Comment: Understood. I can only go by what is shown :) The deferred version of `on` definitely works as advertised, so please stick with it.

Comment: Using $(document) never fails